# ChooserActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to open a xml file with default application on the phone when clicking a button of my app. after google i found and followed this: http://www.androidsnippets.com/open-file-with-default-application-using-intents , my code is just as:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(_file), "application/*"); 
startActivity(intent);
```

it works on my phone, but the logcat got some errors:

```
01-07 02:42:48.242: E/ActivityThread(11280): Activity com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity$1@417ffc78 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
01-07 02:42:48.242: E/ActivityThread(11280): android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity$1@417ffc78 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
01-07 02:42:48.242: E/ActivityThread(11280):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:763)
01-07 02:42:48.242: E/ActivityThread(11280):    at android.app.LoadedApk.getReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:567)
01-07 02:42:48.242: E/ActivityThread(11280):    at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1055)
01-07 02:42:48.242: E/ActivityThread(11280):    at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1042)
01-07 02:42:48.242: E/ActivityThread(11280):    at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1036)
01-07 02:42:48.242: E/ActivityThread(11280):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:341)
01-07 02:42:48.242: E/ActivityThread(11280):    at com.android.internal.content.PackageMonitor.register(PackageMonitor.java:65)
01-07 02:42:48.242: E/ActivityThread(11280):    at com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity.onCreate(ResolverActivity.java:99)
01-07 02:42:48.242: E/ActivityThread(11280):    at com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivity.onCreate(ChooserActivity.java:53)
01-07 02:42:48.242: E/ActivityThread(11280):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4467)
01-07 02:42:48.242: E/ActivityThread(11280):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
01-07 02:42:48.242: E/ActivityThread(11280):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1925)
01-07 02:42:48.242: E/ActivityThread(11280):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1986)
01-07 02:42:48.242: E/ActivityThread(11280):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:128)
01-07 02:42:48.242: E/ActivityThread(11280):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1152)
01-07 02:42:48.242: E/ActivityThread(11280):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-07 02:42:48.242: E/ActivityThread(11280):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-07 02:42:48.242: E/ActivityThread(11280):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4449)
01-07 02:42:48.242: E/ActivityThread(11280):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-07 02:42:48.242: E/ActivityThread(11280):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-07 02:42:48.242: E/ActivityThread(11280):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
01-07 02:42:48.242: E/ActivityThread(11280):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
01-07 02:42:48.242: E/ActivityThread(11280):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I didn't register anything, and don't know how to fix that "Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()", how can i change my code?

Comment: have u tried it as `startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send ..."));`  and see [this](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=29399) issue

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK, yes i have also tried that way, just the same outcome, only difference is createChooser has a 'title' param

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure but if it works fine AND throws the exception probably you need do nothing about it. It can be problem of your device, for example, error in customised by vendor Android  OS. Try to test it on emulator, if it wouldn't throw an exception, just leave it as is. I think your code is fine.