# Deprecated android method replacement getPath()

Tags: android, deprecated

I have this `getPath` method, it works, but I want to get rid of the warning because it says that the `managedQuery` method is deprecated. How can I implement this exact `getPath` method with no warnings? Thank you.

```
public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        System.out.println("IM IN getPath");
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
```

EDIT: Im getting this logcat error now:

```
10-23 07:19:14.080: E/ActivityThread(594): Activity com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity$1@416c9560 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
10-23 07:19:14.080: E/ActivityThread(594): android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity$1@416c9560 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
10-23 07:19:14.080: E/ActivityThread(594):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:763)
10-23 07:19:14.080: E/ActivityThread(594):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:567)
10-23 07:19:14.080: E/ActivityThread(594):  at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1043)
10-23 07:19:14.080: E/ActivityThread(594):  at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1030)
10-23 07:19:14.080: E/ActivityThread(594):  at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1024)
10-23 07:19:14.080: E/ActivityThread(594):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:341)
10-23 07:19:14.080: E/ActivityThread(594):  at com.android.internal.content.PackageMonitor.register(PackageMonitor.java:65)
10-23 07:19:14.080: E/ActivityThread(594):  at com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity.onCreate(ResolverActivity.java:99)
10-23 07:19:14.080: E/ActivityThread(594):  at com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivity.onCreate(ChooserActivity.java:53)
10-23 07:19:14.080: E/ActivityThread(594):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
10-23 07:19:14.080: E/ActivityThread(594):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
10-23 07:19:14.080: E/ActivityThread(594):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
10-23 07:19:14.080: E/ActivityThread(594):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
10-23 07:19:14.080: E/ActivityThread(594):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
10-23 07:19:14.080: E/ActivityThread(594):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
10-23 07:19:14.080: E/ActivityThread(594):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-23 07:19:14.080: E/ActivityThread(594):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-23 07:19:14.080: E/ActivityThread(594):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
10-23 07:19:14.080: E/ActivityThread(594):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-23 07:19:14.080: E/ActivityThread(594):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-23 07:19:14.080: E/ActivityThread(594):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
10-23 07:19:14.080: E/ActivityThread(594):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
10-23 07:19:14.080: E/ActivityThread(594):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: using a CursorLoader as stands in the documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just replace it by `getContentResolver.query()`

so it will look like this.

```
public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        System.out.println("IM IN getPath");
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
```

Comment: thanks that worked but Im getting a logcat error now (see edit). Its not affecting my program but I still think that it should be taken care of. Maybe.

Comment: I think that error has nothing to do with the code above.
see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11308260/chooseractivity-has-leaked-intentreceiver or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14190551/chooseractivity-has-leaked-intentreceiver-com-android-internal-app-resolveractiv

Answer (score 0):

Try this - it works

```kotlin
fun getPath(context: Context?, uri: Uri?): String? {
    print(uri)
    if (uri == null)
        return null
    
    val projection = arrayOf(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA)
    val cursor: Cursor? = context?.contentResolver?.query(uri, projection, null, null, null)
    val path = if (cursor != null) {
        val columnIndex: Int = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA)
        cursor.moveToFirst()
        cursor.getString(columnIndex)
    } else null
    cursor?.close()
    return path
}
```

New Problem "'DATA: String' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java Q"

```kotlin
MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA
```